Add entry to tkinter without window border
I'm creating a borderless window like this
def _create_window(self):
        if self.current_window is not None:
            return
        self.mouse_listener = MouseListener(
            on_left_mouse_click=self.on_left_mouse_pressed,
            on_right_mouse_click=self.on_right_mouse_pressed,
        )

        threading.Thread(
            target=self._run_tkinter_window,
        ).start()

    def _run_tkinter_window(self):
        self.current_window = tk.Tk()
        
        # Make the window borderless
        self.current_window.overrideredirect(True)
        # self.current_window.title("Ctrl + Space Pressed!")

        self.width = 500
        self.height = 50

        if self.config is not None:
            self.width = self.config["window_settings"]["width"]
            self.height = self.config["window_settings"]["height"]

        self.current_window.geometry(f"{self.width}x{self.height}")

        screen_width = self.current_window.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = self.current_window.winfo_screenheight()

        x = (screen_width // 2) - (self.width // 2)
        y = (screen_height // 2) - (self.height // 2)

        self.current_window.attributes("-topmost", True)
        self.current_window.protocol(
            "WM_DELETE_WINDOW",
            self._close_window,
        )

        self.current_window.geometry(
            f"{self.width}x{self.height}+{x}+{y}",
        )

        self.entry = tk.Entry(
            self.current_window,
            font=(
                "Helvetica",
                16,
            ),
        )

        self.entry.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

        # Ensure the Entry widget receives keyboard input correctly
        # self.entry.bind("<FocusIn>", self.on_focus)

        self.current_window.update_idletasks()
        self.current_window.mainloop()

I want to make something like a macos's spotlight search in Ubuntu. But when the window appears the text is entering somewhere in the bottom right corner of the screen.

And if I comment out this line
self.current_window.overrideredirect(True)

it works as expected.

What is the problem with it? Can I somehow get the expected behavior in a chromeless window?

It is better not running tkinter application in a child thread.

it's not a tkinter application, it's a system daemon which opens an tkinter window on demand but must continue running after the window is destroyed. On the main thread, after the window was destroyed the whole app stopped which was not what I needed. That's why I decided to launch each instance of tkinter in a new thread

Then it is still better not running mainloop() in a child thread.

Why? I'm new to python

Ok, I asked chat gpt why it's better not to do it, and the reply is pretty clear. But i haven't found a way to do it correctly. Still i believe it's not the issue in my case
